# What is Inject Method in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

What does the `inject` method in Groovy actually do? I googled it, and have not found the exact answer. Can anyone specify its use with a simple example?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

It applies an operation to a collection and keeps track of an intermediate value.  Take this example: `[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0, { sum, value -> sum + value })`.  This says use 0 as the initial value and apply the addition operation to the intermediate result and each element in sequence.  Each application of the operation generates a new intermediate result.  In this case, the closure adds up the numbers, so it generates the sum of the list.  You can imagine it like:

```
<initial value> <operation> <element1> <operation> ... <elementn>
```

Or, in the case of `[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(0, { sum, value -> sum + value })`:

```
0 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
```

To find the product of a list, you can use `[1, 2, 3, 4].inject(1, { product, value -> product * value})`.  In this case, 1 is used as the initial value, since it is the identity value for mulitplication.

Here's an example that splits a list of multi-word strings into a flat list of words:

```
strings = ["", "this", "is a", "test of inject!"]
words = strings.inject([], { list, value -> list + value.tokenize() })
assert words == ["this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "inject!"]
```

Other terms that are sometimes used to describe this operation are "reduce", as in [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce), or a "fold" (specifically a [foldl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29)).

Comment: could you say in the example, what does tokenize does?

Comment: Tokenize just splits a string on whitespace.  It's the same as String.split except it returns a list rather than an array.

Comment: A very odd choice of method name - I wonder why it wasn't named reduce or fold?

Comment: The name `inject` comes from smalltalk by way of ruby.

Comment: I appreciate that sum is done with inject for the sake of giving example. However in Groovy you may just do `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].sum()`.