# Transform while loop into closure in Groovy

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

How to transform the following while code in groovy into groovy closures. Is it possible ?

```
 List<String> list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5"]
 List<String> res = []
    int index = 0
    while (index < res.size()) {
      String cur = list[index]
      if (cur.endsWith(":")) {
        String next = list[index + 1] /*out of bounds won't happen*/
        res.add(cur + "\n" + next)
        index = index + 2
      } else {
        res.add(cur)
        index++
      }
    }
assert res == ["s1", "s2", "s3:s4", "s5"]
```

I thought of the following solution, but seems like its not working:

```
 List<String> list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5"]
 List<String> res = list.eachWithIndex { int index, String cur ->
   if (cur.endsWith(":")) {
     String next = list[index + 1] /*Out of bounds won't happen*/
     index = index + 2
     return cur + "\n" + next
   }
   return cur
 } as List<String>
assert res == ["s1", "s2", "s3:s4", "s5"]
```

I get this remark in my above code that "`index = index + 2` is never used"

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the list ? Please update your question with some sample data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the `inject` method (though this does mutate elements of the list, which seems dicey):

```
def list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5"]

def res = list.inject([], { acc, item ->
    def lastItem = acc.isEmpty() ? null : acc.last()

    if (lastItem?.endsWith(":")) {
        acc[-1] += item
    } else {
        acc << item
    }

    acc
}) 

assert res == ["s1", "s2", "s3:s4", "s5"]
```

Here, `acc` is the "accumulated result list" and `item` is the current item in the original list. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5209286/12704): the `inject` method is also known as `reduce` or `fold` in other languages.

Comment: nice! `acc[lastIndex]` could just be `acc[-1]` i think and save a line

Comment: good point... Thanks @thehole - I've updated the post.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer similar to Michael Easter's with inject:

```
def list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5"]

def res = list.inject([]) { acc, item ->
  if (acc && acc[-1].endsWith(':')) 
    item = acc.removeLast() + item

  acc + item
}

assert res == ["s1", "s2", "s3:s4", "s5"]
```

with perhaps a few less characters.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the *grooviest* of all existing solution, but it works for your example:

```
list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5:"]

res = []

list.eachWithIndex 
    {e, i -> if (i > 0 && list[i-1].endsWith(":")) {return} 
             if (e.endsWith(":") && i <  list.size-1) {res.add("${e}${list[i+1]}") } else {res.add(e)}}
```

which returns `[s1, s2, s3:s4, s5:]` as expected

You process each element in the list and

if the preceding element exists and is suffixed: do *nothing*

if the *current* element is suffixed and is not last: concatenate the current element with the next.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my second solution. It doesn't use closures but is arguably "functional". Note that it is not a great idea for large lists:

```
def list = ["s1", "s2", "s3:", "s4", "s5"]

def str = list.join(",")
// e.g. s1,s2,s3:,s4,s5

str = str.replaceAll(/\:,/, ":")
// e.g. s1,s2,s3:s4,s5

def res = str.split(",")
assert res == ["s1", "s2", "s3:s4", "s5"]
```